# TSQL: UPDATE Get num rows updated

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008, sql-update

I have an update statement like this:

```
UPDATE TABLE1
SET TABLE1.COL = TABLE2.COL
FROM TABLE1
INNER JOIN TABLE2 ON TABLE1.TAB2ID = TABLE2.ID
WHERE TABLE1.COL1 = '123'`
```

The question of whether there is a way to know how many records were actually updated.

Such as `MERGE` the `OUTPUT $ACTION` command.

Comment: By "actually updated" do you mean rows _touched_ by the query or rows in which a value was altered to a _different_ value? The query could, based on the `where` clause, touch 666 rows, but only 42 might have the value changed to something other than `123`. `@@RowCount` returns the first value. A trigger could use the `inserted` and `deleted` tables to determine the second value.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To identify the number of rows affected by an operation, you're looking for [@@ROWCOUNT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/rowcount-transact-sql)

Answer (score 3):

You need to collect the stats as you Want, but `@@ROWCOUNT` return this:

```
declare @ABC table (
ColName varchar(32)
)

insert into @ABC values ('A')
insert into @ABC values ('B')
insert into @ABC values ('C')
update @Fish set ColName= 'D' where ColName= 'C'
select @@ROWCOUNT  --Count 1

update @ABC set ColName= 'X'
select @@ROWCOUNT -- Count 3
```

Here Offical Source

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187316(v=sql.110).aspx

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/rowcount-transact-sql

Answer (score 2):

You can use @@ROWCOUNT for this.

If the `UPDATE` is part of a user-defined function, you can `RETURN` it, like this...

```
UPDATE
  TABLE1
SET
  TABLE1.COL = TABLE2.COL
FROM
  TABLE1
INNER JOIN
  TABLE2
ON
  TABLE1.TAB2ID = TABLE2.ID
WHERE
  TABLE1.COL1 = '123'
;

RETURN @@ROWCOUNT
;
```

If it's just a standard `UPDATE` query, you can use `SELECT @@ROWCOUNT` immediately after the update to see how many rows were affected.